# Do know you an IDE online for language RPG

Tags: rpg

Do know you an IDE online on Web ?

I would like to test this code

```
dow (a <= 5) and (b + c = 0);
       do_something (a:b:c);
enddo;
```

Comment: I don't think one exists :(

Comment: Some here are ruthless hard lined about things like "[What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"or "[What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)" and might perhaps try to close a question like this.  See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any RPG interpreter online.

There is a free IBM i machine that you can sign up for at pub400.com.